# Can I get the user's api key and store it in my server using google OAuth?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I'm developing a chrome extension using maps API which autofills the address in the address fields of the current page. For testing purpose, I'm currently using my own API key. But I see using this API key I can hit only 25000 requests per day. So I thought of using the user's API key, whoever uses this extension. Using OAuth, I can get the user's consent for accessing his information but can I get his API key and use it that way? I have set up a server so that I can store the user's API key to be used again. Also for the user' consent, I use my API key and client id. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you asking if this is *possible*, or are you asking if this is *permitted*?

Comment: I wanna know both - if it's possible and permitted.

Comment: Possible might, possibly, be on-topic. Permitted is clearly off-topic for Stack Overflow, as it involves legal/contract issues, not programming (I would be surprised if what you want to do is permitted, but judging that is not something Stack Overflow does). I would suggest that you [edit] your question to clarify that you are only interested in possible, not permitted.